# If I append more than one of the same thing to a list and i want to get rid of one of them how do i know which one it is?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I am making a little game. I control a ship and I shoot other little enemy ships. They will drop loot for me to pick up. If I shoot 10 ships and they all drop loot, that's 10 loot to append to a list and if I pick up 1 loot how can I know which loot to remove from the list?

```
    import pygame
    import time
    import random

    pygame.init()

    white = (255,255,255)
    black = (0,0,0)
    red = (255,0,0)
    green = (0,255,0)
    blue = (0,0,255)

    display_width = 800
    display_height = 600

    gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Destroyer')

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    FPS = 60

    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)

    #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Other Functions~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#

    def devMode(x, y, shipW, shipH, xcross, ycross, face):
        devText = font.render("X: "+str(x) + "      Y: "+str(y) + "     shipW: "+str(shipW) + "     shipH: "+str(shipH) + "     xcross: "+str(xcross) + "       ycross: "+str(ycross) + "       Face: "+str(face), True, white)
        gameDisplay.blit(devText,(0,display_height-17))

    def money(count):
        text = font.render("Asteroids: "+str(count),True ,white)
        gameDisplay.blit(text,(0,0))

    def rot_center(image, rect, angle):
        rot_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)
        rot_rect = rot_image.get_rect(center=rect.center)
        return rot_image,rot_rect


    #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~The Game~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#

    def game_loop():

        face = 1

        asteroids = 0

        fthrust = False

        xcross = False
        ycross = False

        loot_spawnx = random.randrange(0,display_width)
        loot_spawny = random.randrange(0,display_height)
        loot_width = 20
        loot_height = 20

        x = (display_width * 0.45)
        y = (display_height * 0.45)

        x_change = 0
        y_change = 0

        shipspeed = 5

        bulSpeed = 10

        cooltime = 10000
        duration = 5000

        newGame = True

        lastTime = 0
        boost = True
        cooldown = False
        power = True

        #Start of bullets

        #1

        lGun1 = -999
        rGun1 = -999

        yBul1 = 0
        xBul1 = 0

        fire1 = 0

        b1 = False

        ybul1_change = 0
        xbul1_change = 0

        #End of bullets

        shipW = 69
        shipH = 88

        shipImg = pygame.image.load('ship1.png')
        forwardthrust = pygame.image.load('ship1_forwardthrust.png')
        reversethrust = pygame.image.load('ship1_reversethrust.png')
        strafe = pygame.image.load('ship1_strafe.png')

        gameExit = False

        while not gameExit:

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        #shipImg, newRect = rot_center(shipImg,oldRect,90)
                        #gameDisplay.blit(shipImg, newRect) 
                        shipImg = pygame.transform.rotate(shipImg,90)
                        face -= 1
                        face = (face - 1) % 4
                        face += 1

                        if face == 2 or face == 4:
                            shipW = 88
                            shipH = 69
                        else:
                            shipW = 69
                            shipH = 88

                    elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        #shipImg, newRect = rot_center(shipImg,oldRect,-90)
                        #blit(shipImg, newRect) 
                        shipImg = pygame.transform.rotate(shipImg,-90)
                        face -= 1
                        face = (face + 1) % 4
                        face += 1

                        if face == 2 or face == 4:
                            shipW = 88
                            shipH = 69
                        else:
                            shipW = 69
                            shipH = 88

                    elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        if face == 1:
                            y_change = -shipspeed
                            x_change = 0
                        elif face == 2:
                            x_change = shipspeed
                            y_change = 0
                        elif face == 3:
                            y_change = shipspeed
                            x_change = 0
                        elif face == 4:
                            x_change = -shipspeed
                            y_change = 0
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        if face == 1:
                            y_change = shipspeed
                            x_change = 0
                        elif face == 2:
                            x_change = -shipspeed
                            y_change = 0
                        elif face == 3:
                            y_change = -shipspeed
                            x_change = 0
                        elif face == 4:
                            x_change = shipspeed
                            y_change = 0
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                        y_change = 0
                        x_change = 0
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_PAGEUP:
                        if face == 1:
                            x_change = -shipspeed
                            y_change = 0
                        elif face == 2:
                            y_change = -shipspeed
                            x_change = 0
                        elif face == 3:
                            x_change = shipspeed
                            y_change = 0
                        elif face == 4:
                            y_change = shipspeed
                            x_change = 0
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_PAGEDOWN:
                        if face == 1:
                            x_change = shipspeed
                            y_change = 0
                        elif face == 2:
                            y_change = shipspeed
                            x_change = 0
                        elif face == 3:
                            x_change = -shipspeed
                            y_change = 0
                        elif face == 4:
                            y_change = -shipspeed
                            x_change = 0

                    elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                        if power == True:
                            power = False
                            if boost == True:
                                shipspeed = 10
                                start = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                                if now - start >= duration:
                                    boost = False
                                    shipspeed = 5
                                    cooldown = True
                                    lastTime = pygame.time.get_ticks()

                    elif event.key == pygame.K_f:
                        #1
                        if b1 == False:
                            fire1 = face
                            if fire1 == 1 or fire1 == 3:
                                xbul1_change = 0
                                xBul1 = 0
                                lGun1 = x + 9
                                rGun1 = x + 59
                                if fire1 == 1:
                                    ybul1_change = -bulSpeed
                                    yBul1 = y - 10
                                else:
                                    ybul1_change = bulSpeed
                                    yBul1 = y + 88
                            else:
                                ybul1_change = 0
                                yBul1 = 0
                                lGun1 = y + 9
                                rGun1 = y + 59
                                if fire1 == 2:
                                    xbul1_change = bulSpeed
                                    xBul1 = x + 88
                                else:
                                    xbul1_change = -bulSpeed
                                    xBul1 = x - 10
                            b1 = False

            if y < loot_spawny+loot_height and y > loot_spawny or y + shipH < loot_spawny+loot_height and y + shipH > loot_spawny:
                ycross = True

                if x < loot_spawnx +loot_width and x > loot_spawnx or x + shipW > loot_spawnx and x + shipW < loot_spawnx + loot_width:
                    loot_spawnx = random.randrange(0,display_width)
                    loot_spawny = random.randrange(0,display_height)
                    asteroids += 10
                    xcross = True
                elif x + shipW > loot_spawnx + loot_width and x < loot_spawnx:
                    loot_spawnx = random.randrange(0,display_width)
                    loot_spawny = random.randrange(0,display_height)
                    asteroids += 10
                    xcross = True
                else:
                    xcross = False
            else:
                ycross = False

            if x > loot_spawnx and x < loot_spawnx + loot_width or x + shipW > loot_spawnx and x + shipW < loot_spawnx + loot_width:
                xcross = True

                if y < loot_spawny+loot_height and y > loot_spawny or y + shipH < loot_spawny+loot_height and y + shipH > loot_spawny:
                    loot_spawnx = random.randrange(0,display_width)
                    loot_spawny = random.randrange(0,display_height)
                    asteroids += 10
                    ycross = True
                elif y + shipH > loot_spawny + loot_height and y < loot_spawny:
                    loot_spawnx = random.randrange(0,display_width)
                    loot_spawny = random.randrange(0,display_height)
                    asteroids += 10
                    ycross = True
                else:
                    ycross = False
            else:
                xcross = False

            if y + shipH > loot_spawny + loot_height and y < loot_spawny:
                ycross = True
                if x + shipW > loot_spawnx + loot_width and x < loot_spawnx:
                    xcross = True
                    loot_spawnx = random.randrange(0,display_width)
                    loot_spawny = random.randrange(0,display_height)
                    asteroids += 10
                else:
                    xcross = False
            else:
                ycorss = False

            now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            if cooldown == True:
                nowTime = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                if nowTime - lastTime >= cooltime:
                    lastTime = nowTime
                    cooldown = False
                    boost = True
                    power = True
                    pygame.display.update()



            gameDisplay.fill(green)

            y += y_change
            x += x_change

            if x <= -5:
                x += 5
            elif x + shipW >= display_width:
                x -= 5
            elif y <= -5:
                y += 5
            elif y + shipH >= display_height:
                y -= 5

            #oldRect = shipImg.get_rect(center=(x + (shipW/ 2), y + (shipH / 2))) 
            #gameDisplay.blit(shipImg, oldRect)

            gameDisplay.blit(shipImg, (x, y))

    ##        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    ##            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
    ##                gameDisplay.blit(forwardthrust, (x + 19, y + shipH))
    ##                gameDisplay.blit(forwardthrust, (x + 42, y + shipH))

            #1
            if fire1 == 1 or fire1 == 3:
                pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [lGun1, yBul1, 2, 10])
                pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [rGun1, yBul1, 2, 10])
            elif fire1 == 2 or fire1 == 4:
                pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [xBul1, lGun1, 10, 2])
                pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [xBul1, rGun1, 10, 2])


            #1
            yBul1 += ybul1_change
            xBul1 += xbul1_change

            pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, blue, [loot_spawnx, loot_spawny, loot_width, loot_height])
            money(asteroids)
            devMode(x, y, shipW, shipH, xcross, ycross, face)
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(FPS)

    game_loop()
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
```

If anyone knows of a better way of doing this other than appending to lists then i am all ears.

Comment: show code please. See [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: In this example, *why does it matter which one?*

Comment: @Ruarri and which part is causing problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are endless possibilities here, You just need to somehow identify your ship with the loot.

I am hoping all ships are different carrying different loots. Like big, small.

So let's say

```
>>> ships = [5, 67, 3, 10]
>>> loot = [100, 30, 300, 50]
```

so say my Ship No. 67 dies. You can even use names here 'a', 'b'. 
We will remove the ship and it's loot.

First let's store it's index before removing it.

```
>>> index = ships.index(67)
```

Now let's remove it.

```
>>> ships.remove(67)
```

Finally remove the loot. Previously using remove method we remove the exact element. Here using del we give the index which needs to be removed.

```
>>> del loot[index]

>>> ships
[5, 3, 10]
>>> loot
[100, 300, 50]
```

Here you can also increase/decrease loot, say ship doesn't die but has only dropped some loot.

But ideally you should make a dictionary of {shipNo:loot} which would be much easier, with better access times.

Comment: I am still not 100% clear with lists but this seems to make sense, although how would i spawn in more than one enemy without having to copy a chunk of code for each ship?

Comment: What do you mean by "how would I spawn in more than one enemy' please me more clear.

Comment: Ok, let's say for me to draw/blit more than one thing such as 10 bullets, I would copy a chuck of code for each bullet.
For the other bullets instead of a 1 after each word it would be a 2 or a 3 and so on.
If you go to the bottom of my code in my question above, look for the "#1". This is how i define each bullet, I cut out the rest all the way up to 10 because of the character limit.
The point is for me to blit or draw more than one of the same thing, I would have to copy a chunck of code and paste it each time i wanted to blit/draw it. Hopefully this clears up things.